# Get value of each latest record grouped by ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of data records which are stored over time, looking roughly like this :

```
|| ID || timestamp || position || value || field1 || field2 ||
```

And another table representing geographic points looking roughly like this :

```
|| ID || position || field1 || field2 ||
```

Where field1 and field2 of each table are in the same category (which enables me to compare them)

I have a query that gives me the closest point (from the points table) to each record, looking like this :

```
SELECT B.ID, A.timestamp as date, A.value, A.field1, A.field2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (ID) * FROM records) AS A
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT *
                    FROM points
                    ORDER BY A.position <-> geom
                    LIMIT 1) AS B
WHERE A.field1 = B.field1
AND A.field2 = B.field2
```

Which allows me to know exactly from what point the value of a record comes from.

I need to get the latest value for each point, and I started like this :

```
SELECT B.ID, MAX(A.timestamp) as date, A.field1, A.field2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (ID) * FROM records) AS A
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT *
                    FROM points
                    ORDER BY A.position <-> geom
                    LIMIT 1) AS B
WHERE A.field1 = B.field1
AND A.field2 = B.field2
GROUP BY B.ID, A.field1, A.field2
```

But I don't know how to get the value from the data records in my result set, right now if I simply add it at the top, it asks me to add it in the `GROUP BY` clause.

I've read on other answers that I need to use a INNER JOIN or LATERAL JOIN, but in this case it searches the closest point to each record a second and it considerably slows the request. Is there any way to avoid doing the request two times and then match them using field1 and field2 ?

EDIT:

Here's how the data records look like (the position are really long and not relevant so I decided to not show them)

```
ID  |      timestamp      |   position   | value |   field1   |  field2
----|---------------------|--------------|-------|------------|-----------
001 | 2019-05-03 17:50:00 |    {....}    |   5   |   South    |  Forward
----|---------------------|--------------|-------|------------|-----------
002 | 2019-05-03 17:55:00 |    {....}    |  17   |   South    |  Forward
----|---------------------|--------------|-------|------------|-----------
003 | 2019-05-03 18:30:00 |    {....}    |   0   |   South    |  Backward
----|---------------------|--------------|-------|------------|-----------
004 | 2019-05-03 13:20:00 |    {....}    |  25   |    West    |  Forward
----|---------------------|--------------|-------|------------|-----------
005 | 2019-05-03 14:30:00 |    {....}    |  36   |    West    |  Backward
----|---------------------|--------------|-------|------------|-----------
006 | 2019-05-03 16:00:00 |    {....}    |  12   |    West    |  Backward
```

After running my first query (to get the closest point), I get this :

```
 B.ID |      timestamp      | value |   field1   |  field2
------|---------------------|-------|------------|-----------
 475  | 2019-05-03 17:50:00 |   5   |   South    |  Forward
------|---------------------|-------|------------|-----------
 263  | 2019-05-03 17:55:00 |  17   |   South    |  Forward
------|---------------------|-------|------------|-----------
 157  | 2019-05-03 18:30:00 |   0   |   South    |  Backward
------|---------------------|-------|------------|-----------
 957  | 2019-05-03 13:20:00 |  25   |    West    |  Forward
------|---------------------|-------|------------|-----------
 547  | 2019-05-03 14:30:00 |  36   |    West    |  Backward
------|---------------------|-------|------------|-----------
 547  | 2019-05-03 16:00:00 |  12   |    West    |  Backward
```

Where B.ID correspond to the closest point to the record position.

What I get when running the query to get the latest record for each [ID / field1 / field2] combination is this :

```
 B.ID |      timestamp      |   field1   |  field2
------|---------------------|------------|-----------
 475  | 2019-05-03 17:50:00 |   South    |  Forward
------|---------------------|------------|-----------
 263  | 2019-05-03 17:55:00 |   South    |  Forward
------|---------------------|------------|-----------
 157  | 2019-05-03 18:30:00 |   South    |  Backward
------|---------------------|------------|-----------
 957  | 2019-05-03 13:20:00 |    West    |  Forward
------|---------------------|------------|-----------
 547  | 2019-05-03 16:00:00 |    West    |  Backward
```

Where as you can see only the before-the-last row disappeared, because it had the same combination as the last one on (ID / field1 / field2) and it was older.

And what I'd like is this :

```
 B.ID |      timestamp      | value |   field1   |  field2
------|---------------------|-------|------------|-----------
 475  | 2019-05-03 17:50:00 |   5   |   South    |  Forward
------|---------------------|-------|------------|-----------
 263  | 2019-05-03 17:55:00 |  17   |   South    |  Forward
------|---------------------|-------|------------|-----------
 157  | 2019-05-03 18:30:00 |   0   |   South    |  Backward
------|---------------------|-------|------------|-----------
 957  | 2019-05-03 13:20:00 |  25   |    West    |  Forward
------|---------------------|-------|------------|-----------
 547  | 2019-05-03 16:00:00 |  12   |    West    |  Backward
```

Comment: can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @mkRabbani Added it!

Comment: I guess you have 2 other table Records and Point. If so, sample data from those table would help.

Comment: The sample data for the records is already there, and the one for the points are pretty simple, ID is integer, position I cannot share, and field1 and 2 are just like the ones for the record (North/South/West/East) and (Forward/Backward).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want `distinct on` again?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.ID) p.ID, r.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.ID) r.* FROM records r
     ) r CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT p.*
      FROM points p
      ORDER BY r.position <-> p.geom
      LIMIT 1
     ) p
WHERE r.field1 = p.field1 AND r.field2 = p.field2
ORDER BY p.ID, r.timestamp DESC;
```

I cannot figure out what you intend by:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT ON (ID) *
 FROM records
)
```

At a minimum, you should have an `ORDER BY`:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT ON (ID) *
 FROM records
 ORDER BY ID
)
```

However, your sample data and the name `ID` suggest that there a no duplicates, so the `DISTINCT ON` may not be necessary.

Comment: You're right I could probably remove the `DISTINCT ON` but this is not the part that I have a problem with right now so I leave it be ? Unless removing the it can help me get the value of each latest row grouped by [ID / field1 / field2], it doesn't really bother me.

Comment: @Adrien . . . This answers what you want to do.  I just have no idea why you are using `DISTINCT ON` in the subquery.

Comment: The `DISTINCT ON` is useless indeed, I'm just saying whether it's there or not doesn't change the result of the request. Also, it does not answer what I want. I'm not trying to order by timestamp, I'm trying to get _only_ the latest record for each [ID / field1 / field2 ] combination. So if 2 data records share the same point ID, field1 and field2, only the newest one is returned.

Comment: @Adrien . . . That is what the first query does -- now that I've fixed the syntax.

Comment: I've just tested it, it does only return me one record for each combination but not the lastest one sadly, it appears to return me a random one.

Comment: Nevermind, the order was ascending by default, and thus returning the oldests records and not the newests. It works perfectly fine with the right order, thanks a lot